# How to check for duplicate rows (a,b) ~ (b,a) in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

Say I have two tables (ids1, ids2 with column headers id1,id2 respectively)

```
+-----+----+  
| id1 | id2|  
+-----+----+  
| 1 | 3  |  
| 2 | 4  |  
| 3 | 1  |  
| 4 | 2  |   
| 5 | 0  |   
+--------+
```

How do I remove the (a,b) ~ (b,a) rows so that I get

```
+-----+----+  
| id1 | id2|  
+-----+----+  
| 1 | 3  |  
| 2 | 4  |  
| 5 | 0  |    
-----------+
```

It doesn't matter whether I get (1,3) (2,4),  (3,1) (4,2), or a combination of the two.

I am using postgreSQL-9.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT LEAST(id1,id2),GREATEST(id1,id2) FROM t
GROUP by
GREATEST(id1,id2),LEAST(id1,id2)
```

[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/29e46/6)

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the most elegant of solutions, but it will work:

```
DELETE FROM foo
WHERE (id1, id2) in (
SELECT f1.id1, f1.id2
    FROM foo f1
    JOIN foo f2 ON (
        f1.id1 = f2.id2 AND
        f1.id2 = f2.id1 AND
        (f1.id1, f1.id2) > (f2.id1, f2.id2))
);
```

The grater than condition in the join makes sure to not remove both matching rows.